# Ionic 3 for Android 8.0.0 - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:8080/)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I'm trying to run the Ionic 3 app in APK version on an Android 8.0.0 device. I keep getting the error when I run the APK on the device:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost:8080/)
```

. I've already tried updating Cordova Ionic WebView, I've changed the `confi.xml` settings, I've tried using Android 6.0.0., and for each time I rebuilt the app APK and tried running it again on the device, but **nothing** has worked so far.

I've been running the APK on device downloading it from Whatsapp as I normal document, then I authorize the device to install the APK and the app apparently is working, but the error returns. What should I do? I really need to get it working. Any help?

Comment: Is there any services running on port 8080 **on localhost** (that is, running on the mobile phone)?

Comment: I don't know but I run the app on machine through the browser so I added some permissions to the `config.xml`file about localhost ports. Now I'm getting the error "Couldn't find index.html". Do you have any idea what could that be?